# ACUMATICA BQL QUERIES

Tags: acumatica

I need to return records from the database using BQL. I have tried writing the BQL query like this
`TaxZone zone = PXSelectJoin<TaxZone, InnerJoin<LocationExtAddress, On<TaxZone.taxZoneID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.cTaxZoneID>>, InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.bAccountID>>, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<Customer.BAccountID>>>;`
and I get errors

```
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(387): error CS1002: ; expected
```

I have also tried using one DAC like this
`Customer cust = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<Customer.bAccountID>>>;`
I am still getting the error

```
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1002: ; expected
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(383): error CS1002: ; expected
Compiler time, in seconds: 21.1134712
```

Any help on the issue would be really appreciated because I have gone through the documentation, that is the format that is supporsed to be written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TaxZone zone = PXSelectJoin<TaxZone, InnerJoin<LocationExtAddress, On<TaxZone.taxZoneID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.cTaxZoneID>>, InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.bAccountID>>>>, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(graph);
```

[To Construct BQL Statements](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=610ce4e6-85e6-48e1-8a89-317a6a7f0542)